# How can I reset a non-default database between Django unit tests?

Tags: django

I have some Django unit tests that inherit from `django.test.TestCase`. This has been helpful when working with the default database, because Django will "reset" the database between every test; that is, each test is run in isolation, and database objects created in previous tests do not affect the current test.

However, I've began using a second non-default database, and this second database does not get reset between tests like I would expect.  Does Django provide a way to reset non-default databases between unit tests? If not, how can I reset that database to keep my tests isolated?

Note: I'm using Django 1.4.5. If this has changed in more recent versions of Django, I'd be interested in hearing about it.

Comment: What is in the default db?  Pre existing data?

Comment: I am using SQLite for testing.  Thus, an empty in-memory database is created at the beginning of the tests, and should be reset between each test. I create test data manually in each test using django-dynamic-fixture (which is a buggy mess, but not the cause of this problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`multi_db`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.multi_db) option in your test case.

Because flush operations can be expensive, Django only flushes the default database be default.  But,  using the `multi_db` option in your test case instructs Django to flush all databases, not just the default db.

eg. From the Django docs.

```
class TestMyViews(TestCase):
    multi_db = True

    def testIndexPageView(self):
        call_some_test_code()
```

Comment: Thanks alot also - this helped on a related problem I was having with other test involving the secondary database!